# mathematic formula syntactic error when I convert LaTex to markdown with pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc

**Is there any way to convert LaTex file to markdown without so many errors? I don't want do lots of works to fix the errors...**

I use the command: `pandoc -s xxx.tex -o xxx.md` to convert and use the Mou to view it. Here is a piece of code converted by `pandoc`:

```
$$\begin{aligned}
  H_{1}:P(q_{2}|q_{1})=&p=P(q_{2}|\neg q_{1})\\
H_{2}:P(q_{2}|q_{1})=p_{1}&\ne p_{2}=P(q_{2}|\neg q_{1})
\end{aligned}$$
```

Here is the errors:

- it seems correct, but **all the `_` is red**, which shows there are errors. I try to add `\` before every `_`. And in the `$$display$$` formula, if there are more than one subscript signs, Mou will show that this formula illegal.
- and the inline mathematical formula is converted as `$c_{k} = 0$`, but the correct syntactic is `$$$c_{k} = 0$$$` in Mou.

I run the same code on **StackEdit**, an online markdown editor, all the code works well! They are not an error in StackEdit, no `_` errors and `$inline$` errors. But unfortunately, the mechanism of Github Pages seems the same as Mou, rather than StackEdit. I tried to download the **MathJax** and link it to the markdown file, but it is useless.

Thanks!

---

My perpose is to post my summary on the Github Pages. Here is the solution I found(and the problem seems happen on **Mac**):

- To using the subscript sign `_` derectly, rather than adding `\` before each `_`, by adding these code to `_config.yml` in the repo directory:

  ```
  markdown: redcarpet

  redcarpet:
    extensions: [autolink, no_intra_emphasis, strikethrough, tables, with_toc_data]
  ```
- Using the `$inlineMath$` rather than `$$$inlineMath$$$`, we should add a piece of code to the `head.html` or `<head> block`:

  ```
    <!--Here the code is to config the MathJax-->  

    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
      tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],  <!--This line is to set the inline math-->
        processEnvironments: true,
        processEscape: true
      },
      'HTML-CSS': {
        matchFontHeight: true,
        availableFonts: [],
        webFont: 'TeX'
      }  
    });
    </script>

    <!-- Here is the code, link to MathJax -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
    </script>
  ```

Then you will post the beautiful formula with less work :)

Comment: Why would it change? Formulas in markdown use the [same format as latex](https://github.com/cben/mathdown/wiki/math-in-markdown)... You can test it [here](http://www.markdownnotes.com/#/?note=2)

Comment: @Silmathoron Thank you, it seems that there is something wrong with my Mou. It still print `$\sum{i=0}{n}\fran{1}{x}$` on the preview side, rather than the formula I want

Comment: Okay, there is not much documentation on this editor so I cannot help you further, but you should probably have look at [Mathjax](http://mathjax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) to see whether Mou uses it and whether you can use it inside you editor (or test [mpp for atom](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview-plus) or [typora](https://www.typora.io/)).
You could also check whether the red underscores are not just a wrong syntactic detection from Mou.
By the way, 2 `$` signs are enough: `$$c_{k} = 0$$` ;)

Comment: @Silmathoron Thank you~ I will look at the document details later. But in Mou, the `$$display$$ ` correspond to `$$display$$` in LaTex, and `$$$inline$$$` correspond to `$inline$` in LaTex

Comment: @Silmathoron I update the URL and parse the  my summary converted by pandoc into the stackedit. It seems `$inline$` work. Are the syntactic different between them?

Comment: I think `$a = b$` displays it inline whereas `$$a = b$$` is equivalent to latex `\begin{equation}a = b\end{equation}`